# pass the password in su command in linux itself

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am facing some problem, Actually i want to kill the process/script which is running by another user but i have credential of that user. Infact when i am using sudo, command is prompting the below error.

```
csaadm is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

After that i have used the below command but it is asking for password, and i want to pass the password in `su` itself.

```
su pwcadm -p pwcadm -c "kill -9 29205"
```

Is there command please help.

Comment: It is a security feature, not a bug, that password reading commands do so by reading from the terminal and not allowing a password on the command line or being passed on stdin.

Comment: Have we any workaround by which we can execute the command by another user or workaround the for above problem???

Comment: `sudo` is the workaround.  You seem to be using `su` which is a different program.  If the admin has not granted you the necessary privileges, you need to ask for them.

Comment: Also, don't use `kill -9` unless you absolutely have to.  Some sites have a policy to disallow programs which cannot be killed by other means (`kill -2`,  `kill -15`,  etc).

Answer (score 1):

`echo password |su -c "pkill -9 java" user`

Answer (score 0):

If you have root privileges you can use setuid to change the user id of the process/script.
So you can set it to root and start the script as normal user.
More info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)

If you have no root privileges you also shouldn't be able to stop a process of another user.